# Why does maximum likelihood fail in this simple case?

Tags: probability, statistics

$\def\e{\mathrm{e}}$
Suppose one decides to parametrize the exponential probability density in this unorthodox way

$$
f(x; θ) = -θ \e^{θx}, \quad x > 0
$$
where $θ \in (-∞, 0)$.

Then putting the derivative of the log-likelihood with one observation equal to zero gives

$$\frac{-1}{\theta} + x = 0 \iff \frac{1}{x} = \theta $$

this would not be a good estimator of $\theta$ since $1/x > 0$.

From the second derivative of the log-likelihood $\frac{1}{\theta^2} > 0$  we see that we are in presence of a minimum instead of a maximum.

Where did the maximum likelihood procedure go wrong? was it an error in my calculations? the fact that the parameter support is not compact? (but in the ordinary parametrization everything works)

For the existence it should be sufficient that the parameter space is compact and the Likelihood function is continuous on the parameter space.

Comment: If $\theta$ is negative and $\frac{1}{x}=\theta$ , then $\frac{1}{x}$ is negative as well.

Comment: @Peter but $x>0$, the mistake is I found the critical point without accounting for the restriction? How could I fix this?

Comment: With a single observation being $0$, the maximum likelihood will occur when the rate is infinite, i.e. when your $\theta=-\infty$, and this need not be at a zero of the derivative of the log-likelihood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you've used

$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\theta}\log(-\theta)=\frac{-1}\theta\;,
$$

whereas

$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\theta}\log(-\theta)=-\left.\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\log x\,\right|_{x=-\theta}=-\left.\frac 1x\right|_{x=-\theta}=-\frac1{-\theta}=\frac1\theta\;.
$$